# Codeigniter producing array inside database result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

First off, i tried searching the internet for a solution. But i dont really know what to search for as i dont have the right words for it. Maybe someone could point me to an answer already given.

So here is my "problem":

I have 3 tables in my database: user, task, user_task.

user contains users ofcourse. task contains tasks. And user_task is a relation table. It contains an id of a task and an id of a user. (One task can have multiple users, thats why i do it this way.)

The thing i want to do is simple. I want to get a list of all tasks and for each task the users assigned to it.

Something like this: 
Task id: 1, name: do dishes, users: bob, liam.

As far as i came i only got to print a task twice if there were 2 users assigned to it. I got so far, by using a mysql query. Not really CI specific.

The query returns a result() with 2 rows, 1 for the task with the user bob and 1 for the same task with the user liam.

```
array{
      array{
            task_id = "1",
            name = "do dishes",
            user = "bob"
           }

      array{
            task_id = "1",
            name = "do dishes",
            user = "liam"
           }

      array{
            task_id = "2",
            name = "vacuum",
            user = "liam"
           }

      array{
            task_id = "3",
            name = "Take out thrash",
            user = "liam"
           }

      array{
            task_id = "3",
            name = "Take out thrash",
            user = "bob"
           }
}
```

What i want to get is a result with 1 row containing the task and within that row i want an array with each name of the users assigned to it.

```
array{
      array{
            task_id = "1",
            name = "do dishes",
            user = array( "bob", "liam" )
           }
      array{
            task_id = "2",
            name = "vacuum",
            user = array( "liam" )
           }
      array{
            task_id = "3",
            name = "Take out thrash",
            user = array( "liam", "bob" )
           }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Within CI and/or MySQL?

I hope you guys can help me, if i am a bit unclear feel free to ask some specifications.
And as i said: if there is already an answer anywhere, please point me to it!

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your data has inside `$results`;
First make a function which will check task id already inside the new result array.if exists return the index else return flase

```
function get_index($array,$task_id)
{
    foreach($array as $index=>$a)
    {
        if($a['task_id']==$task_id)
        {
            return $index;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now write follwing code to get your desired result inside $new_result

```
$new_result=array();//this will contains your desired result
foreach($results as $key=>$result)
{
    $index=get_index($new_result,$result['task_id']);

    if($index===false)
    {
        $new_result[]=array('task_id'=>$result['task_id'],'name'=>$result['name'],'users'=>array($result['user']));
    }
    else
    {
        $new_result[$index]['users'][]=$result['user'];
    }
}
print_r($new_result);//this will output your desired result.
```

Comment: Fixed my problem! Thanks!
Only thing i have to mark: I am using this code in my Model. (I guess i shouldnt) but also in a controller i guess you should put "$this->" in front of the function you are calling. Otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: you can keep `get_index` function inside a helper so you don't need to use `$this`. You can keep this function inside model or controller. In that case you need to call it proper way.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there isn't any option in CI Active Records to achieve that.
You have to loop your result.

```
<?php

$result = array(
    array(
            'task_id' => 1,
            'name' => 'do dishes',
            'user' => 'bob'
        ),
    array(
            'task_id' => 1,
            'name' => 'do dishes',
            'user' => 'liam'
        ),
    array(
            'task_id' => 2,
            'name' => 'vacuum',
            'user' => 'liam'
        ),
    array(
            'task_id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Take out thrash',
            'user' => 'liam'
        ),
    array(
            'task_id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Take out thrash',
            'user' => 'bob'
        ),
    );


function get_arrayvalues_bykeyvalue($array, $key, $key2, $v2)
{
    $ret = array();
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
        foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        {
            if($arr[$key2] == $v2)
            {
                if($k == $key)
                    $ret[] = $v;   
            }
        }
    }
    $u = array_unique($ret);
    return (sizeof($u) == 1) ? $u[0] : $u;
}

$res = array();
foreach($result as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if($k == 'user')
            $res[$arr['task_id']][$k] = get_arrayvalues_bykeyvalue($result, $k, 'task_id', $arr['task_id']);
        else
            $res[$arr['task_id']][$k] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [task_id] => 1
            [name] => do dishes
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [0] => bob
                    [1] => liam
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [task_id] => 2
            [name] => vacuum
            [user] => liam
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [task_id] => 3
            [name] => Take out thrash
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [0] => liam
                    [1] => bob
                )

        )

)
```

**Demo:**
http://3v4l.org/2E9nP

Comment: This would still return 2 rows. As i tried to use this in my project and directly in MySQL workbench. That is not what i want. Am i being unclear in my problem? Because then i will try to explain it better.

Comment: Apologize, didn't read the whole question. Please check the edited answer. By the way found your question interesting +1

Comment: Still not what i want to achieve. When i add more arrays like 
array(
            'task_id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Vacuum',
            'user' => 'bob'
        ),

This will be the output:

Array
(
    [task_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => do dishes
            [2] => Vacuum
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => bob
            [1] => liam
        )

)

I want each task to be in a different Array, where the users will be an array INSIDE the array of the task. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your model, but how I see it, you can use group_concat

**Model :**

```
$this->db->select('t.id_task, t.name, GROUP_CONCAT(u.name SEPARATOR "-") as users') 
         ->from('tasks t')
         ->join('users_task ut', 't.id_task = ut.id_taks')
         ->join('user u', 'u.id_user = ut.id_user')
         ->group_by(t.id_task);
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result();

/*Result expected :
 Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [task_id] => 1
        [name] => do dishes
        [users] => "John-Peter"

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [task_id] => 2
        [name] => vacuum
        [users] => "Mary-Bob"
    )
) */
```

After that, a simple explode should do the trick in your controller.

**Controller :**

```
$tasks = $this->my_model->getTasks();
foreach($tasks as $t)
{
    $t->users = explode("-", $t->users);
}
```